# How to react to keyboard selection on QtTreeView?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, signals-slots, qtreeview

`QTreeView` has the `clicked` signal, but not `itemChanged` like `QTreeWidget`. I have to use `QTreeView` because it's "model based". Still, if my user select a row with the keyborad, `clicked` won't be sent, and my callback will never be called. What signal should I register to ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `QTreeView` class inherits `QAbstractItemView`, which provides access to the [selection model](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel).

The selection model has [several signals](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#signals) that register changes made to the current item and selection with both mouse and keyboard.

**EDIT**:

Just to be clear, the signals need to be connected like this:

```
selmodel = self.listing.selectionModel()
selmodel.selectionChanged.connect(self.handleSelectionChanged)
```

and the signature of the handler should look something like this:

```
def handleSelectionChanged(self, selected, deselected):
    indexes = selected.indexes()
    if indexes:
        print('row: %d' % indexes[0].row())
```

with `selected` and `deselected` being instances of [QItemSelection](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemselection.html).

Comment: It doesn't seems that sure : `self.listing.currentRowChanged .connect(self.on_listing_clicked)` triggers `AttributeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QTreeView' object has no attribute 'currentRowChanged'` while `self.listing.clicked` works like a charm.

Comment: `self.listing.connect(QtCore.SIGNAL('currentRowChanged()'), self.on_listing_clicked)` fails to trigger anything, not even an error.

Comment: @e-satis. You need to connect to the signals emitted by the *selection model*, not the treeview itself. See my updated answer.

Comment: Cool, it works ! What is this selection model ? What is it for ?

Comment: @e-satis. Conceptually, a selection model follows the patern of the rest of Qt's [model/view framework](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html). That is, it provides a *generalization* which allows you to create a specialized selection model for a custom item model and/or view. Of course, if you don't have special requirements, the default model is normally sufficient as it is.